# Continuity on closed interval implies uniform continuity WITHOUT Bolzano-Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The following result is usually proven using the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem (BWT). Can we prove the result without the BWT?

> Let $a<b$. If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $f$ is also uniformly continuous.

Comment: Can you use that closed intervals are compact?

Comment: The result must use some form of completeness. For example you can use Heine Borel.

Comment: My own instinct is to use the Heine-Borel theorem, in preference to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. I took this method to have been already covered (ouch, no pun intended) by the two preceding comments, but perhaps these should be expanded into an answer, as my nonstandard answer seems to have gone down like a lead balloon - and it certainly shouldn't be the only answer!

Answer (score 3):

Arguing from first principles, I suppose one could prove it like this (although I'm not saying it's a good idea):

Define the *variation* of a function $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is any set, to be the least upper bound of the numbers
$$
\{ |f(x) - f(y)| : x, y \in I \}.
$$

Equivalently, one could define it to be $\sup f(I) - \inf f(I)$.

It is either $+\infty$ (in the extended real number system) or a non-negative real number.

We don't yet know that the variation of $f$ on $I$ is finite even when $I$ is a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous.

For each positive integer $n$, let $P_n$ be the partition of $[a, b]$ into $2^n$ intervals of equal length. Let $v_n$ be the maximum variation of $f$ on any one of the closed intervals of $P_n$.

Because each interval of $P_{n+1}$ is contained in an interval of $P_n$, the sequence $(v_n)$ is decreasing.

(It is not necessarily *strictly* decreasing, of course - and for all we know, $v_n$ could even be equal to $+\infty$ for all $n$.)

A decreasing sequence of non-negative extended real numbers tends to $0$, a strictly positive real limit, or $+\infty$.

Suppose the limit of $(v_n)$ is not $0$. Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $v_n > \epsilon$ for all $n$.

Let $T$ be the binary tree consisting of all the closed intervals from the $P_n$ on which the variation of $f$ is $> \epsilon$.

Now apply König's Lemma. (This follows from the axiom of dependent choice: see [Kőnig's lemma - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma). There is a leisurely discussion of the lemma in Chapter 1 of Richard Kaye, *The Mathematics of Logic* (2007).)
[I've included an account of the lemma in an addendum below,
intended to make this answer more self-contained.  It's mostly a
matter of definitions, and the proof is very straightforward -
corrections are welcome, of course!]

Because $T$ has a vertex in $P_n$ for each $n$, it has infinitely many vertices.

By König's Lemma, therefore, there is an infinite sequence of closed intervals $(I_n)$, where $I_n$ is in $P_n$, the variation of $f$ on $I_n$ is $> \epsilon$, and $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$ for all $n$.

Because the length of $I_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity, the increasing sequence of the left endpoints of the $I_n$ and the decreasing sequence of the right endpoints of the $I_n$ have a common limit, $c \in [a, b]$.

By the continuity of $f$ at $c$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon/2$ if $|x - c| < \delta$ and $a \leqslant x \leqslant b$.

But $c \in I_n$ for all $n$, therefore the variation of $f$ on $I_n$ is $\leqslant \epsilon$ whenever $n$ is so large that the length of $I_n$ is $< \delta$.

This contradiction shows that the limit of $(v_n)$ must be $0$.

Now, given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $n$ so that $v_n < \epsilon/2$. Let $\delta$ be the common length of the intervals of $I_n$.

If $x, y \in [a, b]$ and $|x - y| < \delta$, then $x$ and $y$ lie either in the same interval of $P_n$ or in adjacent intervals.

In either case, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. This shows that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$.

(I must say, the use of König's Lemma feels like overkill. But the proof does have the virtue of proving at the same time that $f$ is bounded.)

### Addendum on König's Lemma

An *alphabet* is a finite set, whose elements are called *characters*.
A *string* is a finite sequence of characters. The string of length
$0$ is called the *null* string, and often denoted by $\epsilon$.
The *concatenation* of strings $a_1a_2\ldots a_m$ and $b_1b_2\ldots b_n$
is $a_1a_2\ldots a_mb_1b_2\ldots b_n$, and $a_1a_2\ldots a_m$ is called
a *prefix* of such a string.

A *language* is a set of strings.  A language $L$ is called
*prefix closed*, or a *tree*, if every prefix of every string in $L$
is also in $L$. (Equivalently, $\alpha a \in L \implies \alpha \in L$,
when $a$ is a character.) If a subset of a tree is also a tree, it is
called a *subtree*.

(This is a restrictive definition of 'tree' - even for the purpose
of stating König's Lemma - but it is all we need here.)

A *binary string* is a string over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$.
The *full binary tree*, here denoted by $S$, is the set of all
binary strings.  A *binary tree* is a subtree of $S$, i.e. a
prefix closed set of binary strings.

For $n \geqslant 0$, let $S_n$ be the set of all binary strings of
length $n$. For $\alpha \in S_n$, let $t(\alpha)$ be the natural
number represented by the binary numeral $\alpha$ (or $0$ when
$\alpha$ is null), so that $0 \leqslant t(\alpha) \leqslant 2^n - 1$.
Then the closed intervals of $P_n$ are
$$
K_\alpha =
\left[
a + \frac{t(\alpha)}{2^n}(b - a),
a + \frac{t(\alpha) + 1}{2^n}(b - a)
\right]
\quad (\alpha \in S_n).
$$
Each $\alpha \in S_n$ has two 'child' sequences $\alpha0, \alpha1$,
and these relations hold:
\begin{align*}
t(\alpha0) & = 2t(\alpha), \\
t(\alpha1) & = 2t(\alpha) + 1,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
K_{\alpha0} \cup K_{\alpha1} & = K_\alpha, \\
K_{\alpha0} \cap K_{\alpha1} & =
\left\{ \frac{2t(\alpha) + 1}{2^{n+1}} \right\}.
\end{align*}

König's Lemma, in the form needed here, states that if $T$ is an
infinite binary tree, then there exists an infinite binary sequence
(i.e. an infinite sequence of $0$s and $1$s), $\beta$, whose
prefixes are all in $T$. That is, if $\beta = b_1b_2b_3\ldots$, then
the $n^\text{th}$ prefix $\beta_n = b_1b_2\ldots b_n$ of $\beta$
belongs to $T$, for all $n \geqslant 0$.

**Proof.** Let $U$ be the subset of $T$ such that $\alpha \in U$ if
and only if $\alpha$ is a prefix of infinitely many strings in $T$.
Clearly, $U$ is a subtree of $T$ (although we don't need this fact),
and $\epsilon \in U$. Let $R$ be the 'parent-child' relation on $T$:
$$
R = \{ (\alpha, \alpha b) : \alpha \in T, \ b \in \{0, 1\}\}.
$$

For $\alpha \in T$, the strings in $T$ that are prefixed by $\alpha$
are $\alpha$ itself together with the strings in $T$ that are
prefixed by $\alpha0$ or $\alpha1$. Therefore, if $\alpha \in U$,
then either $\alpha0 \in U$, or $\alpha1 \in U$, or both.

That is, the restriction of $R$ to a relation on $U$ is
'[left-]total', 'serial', 'entire'. (These terms are synonymous: see
[Serial relation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_relation),
as well as the next reference.)

It follows immediately, using the Axiom of Dependent Choice (see
[Axiom of dependent choice - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice), and
[Dependent Choice (Fixed First Element) - ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dependent_Choice_(Fixed_First_Element)))
that there exists an infinite sequence $(\beta_n)$ in $U$ such that
$\beta_0 = \epsilon$ and $\beta_n R \beta_{n+1}$ ($n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$).

'Choose' any such sequence $(\beta_n)$.

For $n \geqslant 1$, define $b_n$ as the last binary digit of
$\beta_n$, so $\beta_n = \beta_{n-1} b_n$. Then
$$
b_1b_2\ldots b_n = \beta_n \in T \quad (n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots),
$$
as is claimed by the lemma. $\square$

Comment: I meant to remark somewhere that $0.\beta$ is one of the binary expansions of the real number $$\frac{c - a}{b - a} \in [0, 1].$$